# Selecting Records with multiple like statements not working

Tags: crystal-reports

First time poster, long time lurker... I hope I can contribute to this community as much as possible, because the people here are awesome. Anyways, here is my question... I apologize in advanced for my lack of technical terms as I am not a programmer, I do basic programming for work purposes.

I want to select records based off two fields that are in my Group Header section.

The criteria is that these fields need to contain certain text, then if they do contain the necessary text...I want to display another text string or a number in the group header which I will later use in the Select Expert. The problem is, based off the data, either one of the two fields are populated or both are populated. Thus I have been trying the following.

```
IF {FIELD1.NAME} like "*Example*" THEN "Display"
ELSE IF {FIELD2.NAME} like "*Example*" THEN "Display";
```

When I try this I only ever see the "Display" where the FIELD1.NAME is populated. If FIELD2.NAME is populated where FIELD1.NAME is blank, I do not see the "Display".

I will also see the "Display" if both are populated or just FIELD1.NAME is populated... which I would expect, but its just not working in the later.

How can I get "Display" to show if either of the two fields are populated and contain the necessary "*Example*" in the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out... below is the code I used.

```
IF ISNULL({FIELD1.NAME}) and {FIELD2.NAME} like "*Example*"
then "Display"

ELSE IF ISNULL({FIELD2.NAME}) and {FIELD1.NAME} like "*Example*"
then "Display"

ELSE IF {FIELD1.NAME} like "*Example*" and {FIELD2.NAME} like "*Example*"
then "Display";
```

Thanks for for the help on this. I think it was because the null's were not counted for first... that had something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
IF {FIELD1.NAME} like "*Example*" and {FIELD2.NAME} like "*Example*" 
THEN "Display"
ELSE IF ISNULL({FIELD1.NAME}) and {FIELD2.NAME} like "*Example*" 
THEN "Display"
 ELSE IF {FIELD1.NAME} like "*Example*" and ISNULL({FIELD2.NAME}) 
THEN "Display";
```

Comment: Thank you for the help... but that did not work unfortunately.

Comment: What is the value in field1.name fields..I mean what are the possible values